# What are the accepted values for the mtouch --device=VALUE option?

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, command-line-interface

I'm trying to install and launch a compiled MonoTouch application on the iPad simulator from the terminal.  Right now, I am using

```
mtouch --sdk=5.0 --launchsim=MyApp.app
```

The application launches, but regardless of the current state of the simulator, it always launches the app on the iPhone simulator, not the iPad simulator, despite the fact that the app in question set up only for iPad.  The usage for `mtouch` suggests that I can pass a value to the `--device=VALUE` option to specify the type of device to use, but no matter what I put it launches as an iPhone simulator.

My question is, what are the accepted values for this option?  Surely *something* works, because MonoDevelop has no problem launching apps in the right simulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is:

```
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch --launchsim=MyApp.app --device=2
```

Which is the same value as the underlying API being used. That being said it's not really useful. I'll look at adding documentation (--help) about this and support for some string value as well.

Comment: Thanks!  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

The format is following (replace ____ by value):

```
--device=":v2:runtime=____,devicetype=____"
```

To get available runtimes run:

```
xcrun simctl list runtimes
```

To get available device types run:

```
xcrun simctl list devicetypes
```

Example:

```
--device=":v2:runtime=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-0,devicetype=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6"
```

Source: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/3d429a106ba96f10d964fb39a0fa5d93581dceef/tests/mtouch/MLaunchTool.cs